# Como abrir una instancia de navegador con Excel 2016 - Este codigo funcionaba en excel 2010 y IE

Tags: excel

Estoy tratando de abrir una instancia del navegador con Excel 2016 y Windows 10 y no funciona, este mismo codigo funcionaba con Excel 2010 y W7, no estoy pudiendo encontrar el error.

```
Sub Macro_Inicio_Navegador()

the_start:
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    objIE.Top = 0
    objIE.Left = 0
    objIE.Width = 800
    objIE.Height = 600
    objIE.Visible = True

    On Error Resume Next

    objIE.Navigate ("http://google.com")

Do
    DoEvents
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        objIE.Quit
        Set objIE = Nothing
        GoTo the_start:
        End If
Loop Until objIE.ReadyState = 4

Set AllLinks = objIE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a")

For Each Hyperlink In AllLinks
If InStr(Hyperlink.Innertext, " ") > 0 Then
MsgBox "Encontrada"
Hyperlink.Click
Exit For
End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. Necesitamos más información. ¿Qué línea es la que genera el error? ¿Qué error sale?

Comment: Hola!! Concretamente se detiene en la creacion del objeto ie, es decir Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

Comment: Hola!! Concretamente se detiene en la creacion del objeto ie, es decir   Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") ...... ahi se detiene la macro. Les cuento que esa macro funciona con Windows 7 y Excel 2010. En el sistema operativo no tengo el IE, pero tampoco MS explica como habilitar Edge y realmente no se como se haria con otro navegador, si alguien sabe como hacerlo o lo tiene probado me haria un gran favor!! Gracias

Comment: Si no tienes instalado InternetExplorer, no puedes crear un objeto basado en ello. Instala Internet Explorer y tu código debería funcionar. Descárgalo de aqui: https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/help/17621/internet-explorer-downloads

Comment: Fui al link que me dijiste y no me deja instalarlo nuevamente, si se te ocurre como llamar otro navegador y que funcione me vendria muy bien! Gracias

Comment: con VBA se puede llamar a otro navegador pero no se puede controlar como haces con Internet Explorer. Creo que tu mejor baza es arreglar el problema que tienes con IE.